# How to get a list of all indexed page URLs by Google?

Tags: google-search

I have a favorite website that I want to save all the webpages under the directory of `domain.com/scripts`. Saving the each page is achievable through a software, so what I want is a list of the URLs. An ordinary user can obtain "a few hundreds of" URLs through the Google search, like this `site:domain.com inurl:scripts`. But this is not what I want to do for extracting the data. It is inefficient and unstable, Google (probably) might ask you some robot proof tests like Google ReCaptcha. So if they have, or any other third party has, it's more appreciated for me to get the list of URLs for a website. So, Is there a way ?

Comment: How about using its sitemaps?

Comment: nice idea, I didn't try that. If Google is indexing the site from its sitemaps then they should have a sitemap. It should work on at least some websites. thanks, I will try on the site.